# Is it time to rearrange portfolio and put more money in bonds?

Tags: stock-markets, index-fund, rebalancing

57% of my portfolio is invested in stocks. I am considering rebalancing the portfolio and adding more debt funds to it. How to track the market and decide if its time to sell the stocks or buy more? BTW, all my Stock portfolio is Index funds.

Comment: Your guess is as good as anyone else's, but a portfolio that's only 57% equity is relatively conservative already.

Comment: After 9 years of solid growth, I reduced my equity exposure dramatically in January.  I also did this in late 2007.  Do I know anything about the future?  Not a thing.  But as I stated in another thread, keeping it is now more important than making it and therefore full bore risk is no longer for me.  Should you do the same?  I have no clue :->)

Comment: Something to think about, if the S&P500 closes below 2532 at the end of the week, it will be officially in a bear market.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're within 5-10 years to retirement having 50% in bonds is already very conservative. I would suggest that if the market starts going down you start buying more stocks.